# Remove white margin inside Tikz picture in figure

Tags: graphics

For some reason I have a white margin on the left side of the image when I try to app it to the page. How do I get rid of it?

[image]

I have created a minimum code example for you :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


%=========================================================================
%                           Image with border
%=========================================================================
% Arguments:
%  1) Optional image parameter like height or width
%  2) Optional border parameters
%  3) Image path
%  4) Caption
%  5) Label

\newsavebox\framedImageBox
\NewDocumentCommand{\framedImage}%
      {O{width=0.6\linewidth}
       O{draw=black,line width=0.75pt,rounded corners=20pt}
       m
       m
       m}{%
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \savebox\framedImageBox{
            \includegraphics[#1]{#3}}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \draw [path picture={%
                \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {%
                    \usebox\framedImageBox};},#2]%
                (0,0)  rectangle (\wd\framedImageBox,\ht\framedImageBox);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \caption{#4}
        \label{#5}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\framedImage[width=0.8\linewidth]{summer}{a summer day.}{fig:a_summer_day}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, you're missing a `%` at

```
\savebox\framedImageBox{
```

Adding `%` should remove the margin!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


%=========================================================================
%                           Image with border
%=========================================================================
% Arguments:
%  1) Optional image parameter like height or width
%  2) Optional border parameters
%  3) Image path
%  4) Caption
%  5) Label

\newsavebox\framedImageBox
\NewDocumentCommand{\framedImage}%
      {O{width=0.6\linewidth}
       O{draw=black,line width=0.75pt,rounded corners=20pt}
       m
       m
       m}{%
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \savebox\framedImageBox{% Here!!!!
            \includegraphics[#1]{#3}}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \draw [path picture={%
                \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {%
                    \usebox\framedImageBox};},#2]%
                (0,0)  rectangle (\wd\framedImageBox,\ht\framedImageBox);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \caption{#4}
        \label{#5}
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\framedImage[width=0.8\linewidth]{summer}{a summer day.}{fig:a_summer_day}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @FireFly3000: Glad I could help!